# what is the garbage collection logic in Survivor memory. - Is this based on the time which objects are created or based on usage freequency

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection

Garbage collector collects objects after 8 pass between survivor1 and surviovor2. The 8 is not fixed this can be less also according to the heap size. My question what is the removal logic after 8 passes. Is that based on creation time ,I mean deletes old objects or based on usage frequency based I mean less frequently used get garbage collected first. If there is frequency based what is the min limit.

Comment: Why do you think there has to be some additional logic? You already described the logic completely, objects are promoted after surviving eight (or whatever configured number) passes. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects get moved to the other survivor space if they are still live. Promotion to old generation/tenured is based on the number of survived gc cycles. (and liveness of course)
Should add here that if the other survivor space is too small, the oldest objects will prematurely be promoted to old gen/tenured space.

Answer (score 0):

Survivor spaces are provided to give objects more chance to be collected before they get promoted to the old generation (thus reducing the load on the collector for the old gen.)

Objects that are still live in the eden space when a minor GC occurs are mostly copied to the 'to' survivor space, along with any objects that are still referenced in the 'from' survivor space. Large objects that won't fit in the survivor space are copied directly to the old gen (this tenuring).  How many times an object is copied between survivor spaces before being tenured is controlled by the *tenuring threshold*. The value of this has an initial and maximum value, which are 7 and 15 by default (in JDK 8).  These can be set explicitly via command line flags -XX:InitialTenuringThreshold=*n* and -XX:MaximumTenuringThreshold=*n*.

The JVM will adjust the tenuring threshold within the initial and maximum values. An additional flag, -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=*n* (default 50) can be used to modify the percentage of survivor space used a collection.

To answer your specific question, the tenuring of objects is based on lifetime not frequency of access.